# How to get the socket id when parsing through io.sockets.sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io on a Node.js server.

```
for (connectedSocket of io.sockets.sockets) {
    console.log(`TEST: id = ${connectedSocket.id}`) //Why is this 'undefined'? All I want is the unique identifier of each socket in the server.
}
```

Not sure how to fix this, but it has to be super simple. Sorry about the fail code formatting :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of socket.io v3, `io.sockets` is now a `Map` object as shown [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#namespaceconnected-is-renamed-to-namespacesockets-and-is-now-a-map).  You can iterate it directly with:

```
for (let [id, socket] of io.sockets.entries()) {
    // can use socket here
}
```

You can use the newer interface:

```
let socketsArray = await io.fetchSockets();
```

to get you an array of connected sockets.

Note, you can also use `fetchSockets()` with rooms and namespaces as shown [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchSockets).

Comment: Nice, any race conditions that could result from this? It's at the start of my 'connection' event and pretty much all the other stuff is socket.on() functions, but I'm just curious if that's a danger of using await in this case.

Comment: @nickcoding2 - See my latest edits for another option.  I suspect the `.fetchSockets()` uses `await` because it works with clustering and other adapters.  Whether or not `await` there can cause a race conditions depends entirely upon what you're doing in with that result.